# Copying an MKMapView object

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have the following issue using `MKMapView`.

```
let mapRectangle = CGRect(....)
var mapOne = MKMapView(frame: mapRectangle)
... do things with mapOne, setting mapOne.region, rotating it ....

.... later in the code :
var mapTwo = MKMapView(frame: mapRectangle)
mapTwo.setRegion(mapOne.region, animated: false)
```

Here, I expect mapTwo to show the same thing as mapOne did earlier.
But it doesn't happen quite like that.

I noticed that if mapOne has been rotated, then mapTwo does not show the same image anymore.

What do I need to add to the code, so that mapTwo does show the same image as mapOne?

Comment: mapTwo is not a copy of the map one. Just assign `mapTwo = mapOne` instead of recreating it.

Comment: Well, it is not as simple as that. I need a different object. Because later in the code they have different use and they are in fact in different places. I really need to catch all the info from mapOne.

Comment: It's not clear to me.  After rotating map one, map two does not show the same image as map one?  Or map two does not show the same image that map two was previously showing?  You want when something happens to one it also happens to the other?

Comment: If you want mapTwo to follow behaviour of mapOne, you need to implement mapView regionDidChangeAnimated delegate. And in this delegate, check if mapView==mapOne, and if it is, apply the mapTwo region same as this region.

Comment: @Frankie Yes if mapOne has been rotated, mapTwo should show up with the same rotation.